# Single sign on for high performance WebSocket game server?

Tags: c#, database, performance, authentication, server

I am developing a C# game server using `WebSocket` protocol (through WebSocketSharp). Currently, whenever a user log in to the game, I create a token and add it into a `ConcurrentDictionary`. Now that I need a user can only log in once at a time, and in the future, the server program may have multiple instances running on the same or different physical machines, I need to migrate from memory into database.

However, I need a very high performance authentication validation for each WebSocket request (I have a session-like that save the token). Therefore, I intend to cache the tokens from database to memory (the old `ConcurrentDictionary`), because checking database for each request is not an option.

But now I come into another problem of synchronizing. I have two ideas:

- Prevent a second device to log in once a token for that account already exist. The token will be destroy when the user log out. However, it is unreliable, because maybe the user could not log out properly (network problem for example). In that case, the user account may got stuck for the session/token lifetime. If the token lifetime is too short to prevent the problem, then again, my server has to check for the database too frequently.
- Give user the ability to log on again, and if there is already a token, the user can choose to *kick* the other log in, so the first user may be kicked while in game and the new one take place instead (This behavior is similar to Steam games). However, without frequent check to database, how can the server know that the first token is kicked before the expiration time?

Please share some experience and/or any proper solution on this problem.

Comment: What about setting up the cluster such that a user will always be directed to the same server (if up) until their session times out. All load balancers support sticky sessions.

Comment: You should do something like blizzard does. Implement a Auth server and split the game into multiple servers. The Auth server should have a low load, give it will only handle Auth, and let balance game stuff to other ones

Comment: @HashPsi This is actually so simple but I couldnot think about before. If I understand correctly, 2 tokens of a same account will always be on a server memory, right? That way, I can safely assume the server *knows* when a second login is coming. However, since it is on the server memory, not database, do you have any advice in case server crash?

Comment: @Fals I have never played any Blizzard game before, so please clarify if I am wrong at any assumption. My current problem is not really about the load, but about the speed of authenticating for *each `WebSocket` request* (which maybe up to tens of them each second). I think an external server can only slow down the progress?

Comment: @HashPsi Nice explanation. Thank you very much. Please post it as answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting up the cluster such that a user will always be directed to the same server (if up) until their session times out. All load balancers support sticky sessions.

Using stickiness results in a given user going always to the same server. Therefore, you can use an exclusively in-memory mechanism to validate the authentication token. If a server crashes, the LB will typically know that the server is down and will direct the packets to another server. That server should be able to detect that the auhentication ticket is not valid (on that server) and direct the user to reauthenticate. Presumably, this is OK since the state of the game in progress will have been lost when the server crashed.